# Calculating average grade wont succeed

Tags: python, list, output

I have to calculate the average grade of some person in python. I received an input file and in combination with that, I have to calculate everyones average grade. I tried a lot, but I only got the average grade of the first person.. Can someone help me?

The input file is the following:

```
Tom Bombadil__________6.5 5.5 4.5
Dain IJzervoet________6.7 7.2 7.7
Thorin Eikenschild____6.8 7.8 7.3
Meriadoc Brandebok____1.0 5.0 7.7
Sam Gewissies_________2.3 4.5 6.7
```

The output is as follow:

```
Tom Bombadilhas an average grade of 5.5
Dain IJzervoethas an average grade of 5.5
Thorin Eikenschildhas an average grade of 5.5
Meriadoc Brandebokhas an average grade of 5.5
Sam Gewissieshas an average grade of 5.5
```

I used this code:

```
def names(lines):
    for i in lines:
        invoer_split = i.split("_")
        first_name = invoer_split[0]
        print first_name + "has an average grade of %.1f" %(average_grade(names))

def average_grade(names):
    for i in lines:
        grades_split = i.split("_")
        grades = grades_split[-1]
        grades_float = map(float,grades.split())
        grades_average = sum(grades_float)/3
        return grades_average

grades_file = open('grades1+2.in')
lines = grades_file.readlines()

names(lines)
average_grade(names)
```

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of processing the names and grades separately, do them at the same time.  We will change the input into a dictionary mapping strings to a float.

```
with open('filename') as f:
    grades_dict = {}
    for line in f:
        name, *underscores, grades = line.split('_') #I forget when this syntax became a thing.  You might have to assign these separately
        grades = list(map(float, grades.split()))
        grades_dict[name] = sum(grades)/len(grades)

for name, grade in grades_dict.items():
    print('{0} has an avergae grade of {1}'.format(name, grade))
```

Comment: Wow, this looks very complicated for me.. Isn't it possible with a little change in my own code?

Comment: The problem you're having is mostly because you're getting the names and the values separately, so later you can't match the grades to the names they go with.  What part of the above are you having trouble with and I can explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Patrick's solution, you could use this.

```
def average_grade(grades_string):
    # split on whitespace
    grades = grades_string.split(' ')
    # convert to floats (we convert map to list for python3 compatibility)
    grades = list(map(float, grades))
    # return the average
    return sum(grades)/len(grades)

# This is the same as "lines = open()", but closes the file after we finish
with open('grades1+2.txt') as lines:
    # Start iterating
    for line in lines:
        # When we split by underscores, we will get three parts:
        # the name; the empty string (where underscores were); the grades.
        # We can do that in one assignment
        name, ignore_this, grades_str = line.split('_')
        # now print the result (converting average to string)
        print(name + ' has an average of ' + str(average_score(grades_str)))
```